# ajax call with jquery asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax, actionresult

I have a button with the class "btn" and span with id "ajaxtest". When I click on the button I want to put text "test" in my span tag. And this to be done in ASP.NET MVC.

In the View I have the following ajax call:

```
<span id="ajaxtest"></span>
<input type="submit" class="btn" name="neverMind" value="Test BTN"/>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: "get",
                cache: false,
                url: "/MyController/MyAction",
                dataType: 'string',
                success: function (resp) {                       
                    $("#ajaxtest").html(resp);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

In MyController I have the following code:

```
    public string MyAction()
    {
        return "test";
    }
```

I know how Ajax works, and I know how MVC works. I know that maybe the error is because we are expecting something like this in the controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
              //do something here
        }
        //do something else here
    }
```

But actually that is my problem. I don't want to call some partial View with this call. I just want to return some string in my span and I'm wondering if this can be done without using additional partial views.

I want to use simple function that will only return the string.

Comment: Change `$("#ajaxtest").html(resp);` to `$("#ajaxtest").text(resp);`. Additionally, add a `debugger;` in the success function to test the data you're getting back from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change dataType: 'string'  to dataType: 'text'

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".btn").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "get",
                        cache: false,
                        url: "/login/MyAction",
                        dataType: 'text',
                        success: function (resp) {
                            $("#ajaxtest").html(resp);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I check it my local it will work for me

Comment: This was the answer I was about to post and is right.